# PySpark APPEND Mode SaveAsTable API Concurrency Behaviour

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, concurrency

I am trying to save data in append mode in a table. I am wondering what would be the behaviour if there are multiple jobs trying to write in the same table at the same time in Append mode.

Here is the sample code, with which I am trying to write data.

```
df.repartition(5).write.mode("append").partitionBy("partition_id").option("path", path).saveAsTable(table)
```

First, is it recommended to have concurrent writes to a table in pyspark. If YES, how can i eliminate below errors that I have faced while testing out some scenarios.

Scenario 1: 2 Concurrent Jobs

Case 1: when table is not present and it is getting created for the first time.

Observations: One job succeeded and other failed with error that Table already exists.

Case 2: when table is already present.

Observations: Both jobs succeeded without any error.

Scenario 2: 4 Concurrent Jobs

I am expecting that with 4 jobs, Case 1 behaviour will be same.

Case 2: when table is already present.

Observations: 1 job succeeded and other 3 failed first and then in retires all 3 got succeeded as well. Please find the errors below:

Failed Job 1 Errors:

Error 1

```
WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: Exception get thrown in job commit, retry (1) time.
java.io.IOException: Upload failed for '<base_path>/_SUCCESS'
```

Error 2

```
Caused by: com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 412 Precondition Failed
PUT https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/<bucket>/o?ifGenerationMatch=<timestamp_may_be>&name=<base_path>/_SUCCESS&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=<some_token>
{
  "code" : 412,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "If-Match",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not hold.",
    "reason" : "conditionNotMet"
  } ],
  "message" : "At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not hold."
}
```

Failed Job 2 Errors:

Error 1:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to merge directory from <base_path>/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20230415171143_0002_m_000004_41/partition_id=1234 to <base_path>/partition_id=1234

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Failed to rename FileStatus{path=<base_path>/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20230415171143_0002_m_000004_41/partition_id=1234/part-00004-91590a94-c0ba-4ab6-bb49-bfeea928d6e8.c000.snappy.parquet; isDirectory=false; length=848073403; replication=3; blocksize=134217728; modification_time=1681578746177; access_time=1681578746177; owner=<username>; group=<username>; permission=rwxrwxrwx; isSymlink=false} to <base_path>/partition_id=1234/part-00004-91590a94-c0ba-4ab6-bb49-bfeea928d6e8.c000.snappy.parquet
```

Similar errors for Failed job 3 as well.

Spark Version: 2.4.8

Comment: it also depends on the file format used. in Delta Lake it's better than in other file formats

Comment: I dont have Delta Lake on this cluster.